# Let $G$ be a simple group. Show that if $H$ is a subgroup $G$ such that $[G:H]= 3$ then $H=\{1\}$ and $|G|=3$.

Tags: group-theory, simple-groups

**MY ANSWER:** Since $G$ is simple the only normal subgroups of $G$ are $\{1 \} $ is $ G $ itself. As $ G / H $ is a quotient group it follows that $ |H|\neq 3 $ because otherwise the $ H $ index in $ G $ would be 1. Therefore, $ H = \{1 \} $ and therefore $ | G | = 3 $.

*Can you check if my answer is right?*

Comment: Could you check the statement of the problem?

Comment: I can't understand your problem.

Comment: No your answer is not right because you have assumed that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, which it might not be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your argument is thoroughly incorrect (and almost incoherent, to be honest). You do not know that $H$ is normal, you are only told it has index $3$ and is a subgroup. So you cannot assert that $G/H$ is even a group. Moreover, you cannot assert that $|H|\neq 3$, and your reasoning does not make sense; if $|H|$ *were* equal to $3$, that would *not* imply that the index is $1$... at least not immediately; what makes you think it does? It is certainly possible for a subgroup to have the same order as its index, and the order and the index of a subgroup need not be related at all.  All you know is that the subgroup has *index* $3$.

Instead, note that the action of $G$ on the left cosets of $H$ induces a homomorphism $G\to S_3$ whose kernel is a normal subgroup contained in $H$, and since $G$ is assumed to be simple, the kernel must be trivial. Can you take it from there?

Comment: Thank you!! I have this other solution in hands, with this homomorphism. I thought there would be a faster and easier way to resolve.
But with your explanation, it was clear to me that I’ve been carrying errors regarding the interpretation between the meanings of
1) index of a subgroup $H$ of the group $G$;
2) quotient group;
3) $G / H$
Do you advise me to publish the correct answer for the question?

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant that there's a *normal* subgroup of index $3$.  Then you would be correct, if you would note that $H$ can't be a nontrivial proper subgroup.  But it would be if it had index $3$, unless...

In the problem it's not actually necessary to assume $H$ is normal, as @Arturo's solution shows.

Comment: The problem as stated is correct; you do not need to assume $H$ is normal; the proffered solution is a mess, though...

Comment: @ArturoMagidin ok.  I'll take your word for it.

Comment: Or, alternatively, you can look at the solution I am proposing... (rather than just take my word for it)

Comment: I did, and it looks correct.  I took the liberty to edit a typo. @ArturoMagidin

Comment: Thanks!${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score -1):

On page 253 in [this](http://93.174.95.29/main/53F89710839EF36BBFFC51BA905F8638), we see that "Corollary 12.6. Let $G$ be a finite group, and let $H \leq G.$ Assume that $|G : H| = p,$
and let $p$ be the smallest prime divisor of $|G|$. Then $H\unlhd G.$ And your question deduces $p=3.$

Comment: And how did you conclude that $3$ is the smallest prime that divides $|G|$? How did you showthat $|G|$ is not divisible by $2$? For that matter, how did you even prove that $G$ is finite?